# Should we centralized flag into single reducer in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Traditionally for each and every "action" file that has API request, we will implement a set of "standard" objects/flag such as "isLoading, isFailed, isSuccess" in every reducer.

I'm wondering if it's actually a good idea to create a more generic reducer that holds all the "standard" objects/flags, in a way that whatever API requests that being fired, flags in the "generic reducer" will react to it accordingly?

I've tested with it and found that it works great with single screen, and problems kicked in when there is other screens stacked on it. I'm guessing that since both screens are referring to the same flag, and both screens will be re-render together?

Answer (score 0):

The logical way to use flags is to have a unique flag for each independent data collection, or key in Redux store.
The generic key does not include information on which part of the state is loaded or failed, so it isn't a very good solution.
Personally, I use a custom wrapper for my reducers, which automatically creates loading, success and error flags for each of them without me having to re-implement them.
I don't think the level of abstraction with individual flag references can be increased.